# TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined In ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is something wrong in my source code but I'm not able to figure out what - please help

[image]

And my Code

```
const lastFutured = featured.pop();

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <section className="container home">
      <div className="row">
        <h1>Featured Posts</h1>
        <section className="featured-posts-container">
          <PostMasonry posts={featured} columns={2} tagsOnTop={true} />
          <MasonryPost posts={lastFutured} tagsOnTop={true} />
        </section>
        <h1>Trending Posts</h1>
        <PostMasonry posts={trending} columns={3} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your error message image and the code doesn't match. Can you post the right code that causes the issue? Please show us the code for `MasonryPost` component in `masonry-post.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you're not passing `post` prop to the component. Looking at the way, the `MasonryPost` function is defined, it's looking for a `post` prop and not a `posts` prop. Kindly change the following code:

```
<MasonryPost posts={lastFutured} tagsOnTop={true} />
```

To the following:

```
<MasonryPost post={lastFutured} tagsOnTop={true} />
//           ^^^^
```

Use the `post` prop and not the `posts` prop, which might be the right one.

Comment: OMG i very very love u! :v

Comment: @huhu Love you too!  Have a nice day!